# Almacenar la clase inicial de HTML y retornarla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando almacenar el valor inicial de una clase y retornarlo un operador condicional ternario cuando no cumpla las condiciones

He intentado algo como:

```
  function toggleDarkLight() {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");
  var currentClass = body.className;

  var almacenaclaseincial= [claseinicial=document.getElementById("body")];

  body.className = currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode" : 
                   currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode sidebar-slim" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode sidebar-slim" :
                   currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode sidebar-overlay" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode sidebar-overlay" :
                   claseinicial;}
```

EL HTML es bastante extenso pero solo necesito modificar

```
<body class="sidebar-fixed dark-mode" id="body"></body>
```

Comment: Podrias agregar tu HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres solo necesitas capturar la clase antes de cambiarla.  Algo asi:

```js
function toggleDarkLight() {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");
  var currentClass = body.className;
  console.log(currentClass);      

  body.className = currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode" : 
                   currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode sidebar-slim" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode sidebar-slim" :
                   currentClass == "sidebar-fixed dark-mode sidebar-overlay" ? "sidebar-fixed light-mode sidebar-overlay" :
                   currentClass;
  console.log(body.className);
}
toggleDarkLight();
```

```html
<body class="sidebar-fixed dark-mode" id="body">Test</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que busques la lista de clases con `classList()` y luego compares. De esta forma no obvias la posibilidad de tener otras clases con el `className()`

```
function toggleDarkLight() {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");
  var currentClass = body.classList;
  console.log(currentClass);      
     if(currentClass.contains("sidebar-fixed") && currentClass.contains("dark-mode")){
       if((!currentClass.contains("sidebar-slim")) && (!currentClass.contains("sidebar-overlay"))){
          body.addClass("sidebar-fixed light-mode");
      }else{  
         if(currentClass.contains("sidebar-slim")){ 
            body.addClass("light-mode sidebar-slim");
         }
         if(currentClass.contains("sidebar-overlay")){ 
            body.addClass("light-mode sidebar-overlay");
          }
   }
}
toggleDarkLight();
```